# Maximum number of toys task for HackerRank challenge?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem: http://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mark-and-toys

> Mark and Jane are very happy after having their first child. Their son
>   loves toys, so Mark wants to buy some. There are a number of different
>   toys lying in front of him, tagged with their prices. Mark has only a
>   certain amount to spend, and he wants to maximize the number of toys
>   he buys with this money.
>
> Given a list of prices and an amount to spend, what is the maximum
>   number of toys Mark can buy? For example, if  and Mark has  to spend,
>   he can buy items  for , or  for  units of currency. He would choose
>   the first group of  items.

My solution normally works but apparently is incorrect when a very large set of numbers are thrown at it.

```
// Complete the maximumToys function below.
function maximumToys(prices, k) {
    const pricesSorted = prices.sort();
    // console.log('pricesSorted ', pricesSorted);

    let budget = k;
    let noToys = 0;

    pricesSorted.forEach(toyPrice=>{
        if (toyPrice <= budget) {
            noToys++;
            budget = budget - toyPrice;
        }
    });

    // console.log('noToys ', noToys);
    return noToys;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't pass comparable function to `sort()`, it assumes the values as strings and sorts them according to Unicode code points. Source: - [Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

So, pass a comaparable function and JS will sort objects depending upon return value of this function. Rest of your code is correct.

```
const pricesSorted = prices.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

**UPDATE:**

Since the `sort()` sorts in-place, `pricesSorted` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the toys according to price and keep taking toys as long as you have money left.

```
// Complete the maximumToys function below.
function maximumToys(prices, k) {
    var bought = 0
    var pricings = prices.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    var amtLeft = k;
    for (var i = 0; i < pricings.length; i++){
        if (amtLeft < pricings[i]) {
            break;
        } else {
            amtLeft = amtLeft - pricings[i];
            bought++;
        }
    }
    return bought
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function maximumToys(prices, k) {
let cost=0,count=0;
var x = prices.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
for(let i=0; i<prices.length; i++)
    {
        if(cost<k)
        {
            cost+=x[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My JavaScript solution

```js
function maximumToys(prices, b) {
    var t = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var arr = prices.sort((a,b) => a-b);
    for (let j=0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        t += arr[j];
        if (t < b) {i++}
        else {break;};
    }
    return i;
}

console.log(maximumToys([1, 12, 5, 111, 200, 1000, 10], 50));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split_string(string);

// Complete the maximumToys function below.
int maximumToys(vector<int> prices, int k) {


}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    string nk_temp;
    getline(cin, nk_temp);

    vector<string> nk = split_string(nk_temp);

    int n = stoi(nk[0]);

    int k = stoi(nk[1]);

    string prices_temp_temp;
    getline(cin, prices_temp_temp);

    vector<string> prices_temp = split_string(prices_temp_temp);

    vector<int> prices(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int prices_item = stoi(prices_temp[i]);

        prices[i] = prices_item;
    }

    int result = maximumToys(prices, k);

    fout << result << "\n";

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}

vector<string> split_string(string input_string) {
    string::iterator new_end = unique(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), [] (const char &x, const char &y) {
        return x == y and x == ' ';
    });

    input_string.erase(new_end, input_string.end());

    while (input_string[input_string.length() - 1] == ' ') {
        input_string.pop_back();
    }

    vector<string> splits;
    char delimiter = ' ';

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t pos = input_string.find(delimiter);

    while (pos != string::npos) {
        splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, pos - i));

        i = pos + 1;
        pos = input_string.find(delimiter, i);
    }

    splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, min(pos, input_string.length()) - i + 1));

    return splits;
}
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question?